# Rails 3 - associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, model, associations

I print in my view a number that tell me, how many people read my article. It looks something like a:

```
<%=article.hits.count%>
```

As is possible to see, I created a simple association.
Now I am trying to get the information, if the user who is log in on my page, so if he is already had read this article. In my table that contains `hits` is column `user_id`.
But I can't still find the way, how to get...

I tried something like:

```
<% if session[:login_user_id].hits.user_id == session[:login_user_id]%>
  Have you read it already.
<% end %>
```

But the example above doesn't work me... Could anyone help me please, how to do?

**EDIT:** The models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hits
end

class Hits < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, :class_name => "DataHit", :foreign_key => "article_id"
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hit
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add the model with its relation, at least the ones that has something to do with the problem? We need the models `Article`, `Hit` and `User` with the relations in between. Or is the user_id directly stored in the model `Hit` without a relation?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first talk about the model you like to receive. For me, it sounds like:

- Every article can be visited / read by many users.
- Every user can read / visit many articles.
- This is a classical `n:m`-association which is normally implemented by a has-many-through association.

If this is the intention, it should be implemented like:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hits
  has_many :users, :through => :hits
end

class Hits < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, :class_name => "DataHit", :foreign_key => "article_id"
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hits
  has_many :articles, :through => :hits
end
```

Of course, you have to add migrations that ensure that the final DB model is like that:

- Hit has article_id and user_id to ensure that users may find the articles they have read

If you have that model implemented, it should be more easy. Then you have operations available like: `@article.users.contains(User.find(user_id))`. Have a look at the tutorial at [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) which explain what the has-many-through relation is and which advantages they have.

It would be helpful if you try the things first in the console of Rails. To do that, start with:

1. Start the rails console in the root directory of your application: `rails c`
2. Enter there e.g.: `art = Article.find(1)` to get the article with the id.
3. Try which methods are available: `art.methods.sort` to see all methods that could be used. If there is no method `users`, you have did something wrong with the assocication.
4. Try the call: `us = art.users` and look at the result. It should be a rails specific object, an object that behaves like a collection and understands how to add and remove users to that collection (with the whole life cycle of rails). The error your currently have could mean different things:

   - Your database model does not match your associations defined in Rails (I suspect that).
   - Some minor tweak (misspelling somewhere) which hinders Rails.

I hope this gives you some clues what to do next, I don't think that we can fix the problem here once and for all times.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I tried to apply your notes to my app, but I still get an error `undefined method `contains' for #<Class:0x1082c9440>`. I tried to search some information about `contains`, but nothing much I found...